# Convert TTML Subtitles to STL or SRT in Linux

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, linux, command-line, .srt

I want to convert a file with `TTML` subtitles preferably to `STL`, or to `SRT` (less preferred). I thought that I would be able to do it with `ffmpeg` but apparently they do not support it, because the `TTML` is `XML`-based. My main goal is to find a way to do this using the command line, so I can use it in a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ttconv](https://pypi.org/project/ttconv/) Python package will do it. It can be installed with pip.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more formats and better file parsing capabilities, you can use [subtitles package](https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles)

```
php subtiltes.phar input.ttml output.stl
```